How did Kolmogorov's probability theory contribute to the development of quantum mechanics?
I understand that the introduction of probability theory into quantum mechanics came from Max Born, Paul Dirac, and others' papers in 1926. On the other hand, the formalization of probability theory was accomplished a few years later, in 1933, by Andrei Kolmogorov. I am interested in how the development of probability theory influenced quantum mechanics, and whether their developments influenced each other. Can someone provide information on this? Are there any good references on this topic?

Relevant Physics.SE discussion: Why is the application of probability in Quantum Mechanics fundamentally different from application of probability in other areas?.

Thank you for your response. I would have appreciated it if you could introduce something that discusses the historical progression...

My area is mathematical statistics and not physics. But the discussion was pretty standard for me to understand. I felt it apt to mention it here. Hope some others would be able to highlight the chronological advances.

A superficial comment: I think that intuitive ideas of probability had existed for enough centuries that people wanting to understand the "measurement" craziness could rationalize it by talking in terms of "probability". I've not seen any physics-context discussion involving "fancy modern" (Kolmogorov's) probability, measure theory, etc. Much more just as a pseudo-philosophical/intuitive explanation of why quantum stuff does not behave like "macro-world" stuff.
